# Activity overlap？I searched for a long time but still couldn't solve the problem

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I will explain the issue as follows: I click on the search box from the homepage to enter the search interface. The search interface displays two fragments through hide and show methods. When I first enter, the tag interface is displayed. When searching for specific content, the tag interface is hidden and the search details interface is displayed through show(). Now, the problem is that when I quickly enter the search interface and return immediately, and then quickly click the search box again to try to enter the search interface, the search interface cannot be displayed normally, and the Home screen still displays, and no operation can be performed. Only by sliding the screen back can I operate normally. Through the log, I can see that the search interface has indeed been opened, but it cannot be displayed. I tried to search for related issues, but it did not solve the problem. Please help me, thank you.

Here are my code.

```
class SearchActivity : BaseVmActivity<SearchViewModel>() {

    companion object {
        private const val HISTORY_FRAGMENT_TAG = "history_fragment"
        private const val RESULT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "result_fragment"

        fun instance(): SearchActivity {
            return SearchActivity()
        }
    }

    private lateinit var historyFragment: HistoryFragment
    private lateinit var resultFragment: ResultFragment

    override fun viewModelClass(): Class<SearchViewModel> = SearchViewModel::class.java

    override fun getLayoutId(): Int = R.layout.activity_search

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        println("出事了")
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            historyFragment = HistoryFragment.instance()
            resultFragment = ResultFragment.instance()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, historyFragment, HISTORY_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .add(R.id.container, resultFragment, RESULT_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .show(historyFragment)
                .hide(resultFragment)
                .commit()
        } else {
            historyFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(HISTORY_FRAGMENT_TAG) as HistoryFragment
            resultFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(RESULT_FRAGMENT_TAG) as ResultFragment
            println("执行了吗")
        }

        imgBack.setOnClickListener {
            if (resultFragment.isVisible) {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .hide(resultFragment)
                    .commit()
            } else {
                println("触发了")
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(historyFragment)
                    .remove(resultFragment).commit()
                ActivityHelper.finish(SearchActivity::class.java)
            }
        }
        imgSearch.setOnClickListener {
            val text = etInput.text.toString().trim()
            if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                resultFragment.doSearch(text)
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .show(resultFragment)
                    .commit()
                it.hideSoftInput()
                historyFragment.addHistory(text)
            }
        }
        imgClear.setOnClickListener {
            etInput.setText("")
        }
        etInput.run {
            addTextChangedListener(
                onTextChanged = { text, _, _, _ ->
                    imgClear.isGone = text.isNullOrEmpty()
                }
            )
            setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    imgSearch.performClick()
                    true
                } else false
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        supportFragmentManager.putFragment(outState, HISTORY_FRAGMENT_TAG, historyFragment)
        supportFragmentManager.putFragment(outState, RESULT_FRAGMENT_TAG, resultFragment)
    }

    override fun initView() {

    }

    fun fillInputText(content: String) {
        etInput.setText("")
        etInput.setText(content)
        etInput.setSelection(content.length)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        imgBack.performClick()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        LogUtil.d("onPause")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        LogUtil.d("onStop")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        LogUtil.d("onDestroy")
    }
}
```

I want to enter the search interface from the homepage, return to the homepage, and enter the search interface. This process is repeated and always normal